# Retornar resultado em um campo

Tags: javascript

esta é minha primeira pergunta aqui...
Como retornar este valor que está no console.log(converte) para o input com #fahrenheit, que já guardei em uma variavel com mesmo nome?  Já tentei:

```
document.querySelector('#fahrenheit').innerText = converte
```

Mas não funcionou. textContent também não.

```
document.querySelector('#temp-form').addEventListener('submit', calcular);

//função calculadora

function calcular(e){
// pegar o valor em Celsius
const celsius = document.querySelector('#celsius');


// calculos
const principal = parseFloat(celsius.value);
const converte = parseFloat((9 * principal + 160) / 5);


console.log(converte);



 e.preventDefault();
}
```

Além disso, o parseFloat parece não funcionar, pois o campo rejeita valores decimais. Porque?

Segue o HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<title>Conversor de Temperatura</title>
</head>
<body class="bg-info">
  <div class="container mt-5">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
              <div class="card card-body text-center mt-5">

                  <h1 class="heading display-5 pb-3">Conversor de Temperatura</h1>
                  <form id="temp-form">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="input-group">
                              <span class="input-group-text">ºC</span>
                              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="celsius" placeholder="Temperatura em Celsius">
                          </div>
                      </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" value="Calcular" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">
                        </div>
                  </form>

                  <!-- RESULTS -->
                  <div id="results" class="pt-4"><h5>Resultados</h5></div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-text">Fahrenheit</span>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="fahrenheit" disabled>
                        </div>
                  </div>

              </div>

          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: coloque `document.querySelector('#fahrenheit').innerText = converte` no lugar `console.log(converte)`!

Comment: algumas observações: como você não colocou o `html`, não dá pra saber que elemento é o "fahrenheit". Para usar a propriedade `innerText`, deve ser um elemento do tipo `p`,  `div`, `label`,, etc. Se for um `input`, use `value`  (`document.querySelector('#fahrenheit').value = converte`). Se vai buscar o elemento por id, pode usar algo mais específico como `document.getElementById("fahrenheit")` por exemplo. Geralmente usamos `const` para tipos primitivos, como um número ou um texto (por exemplo `const PI = 3.1416`), não para elementos (`const celsius = document.querySelector('#celsius')`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do Virgílio Novic e abordando a questão do `input` não aceitar decimais.

Na resposta acima citada, basta trocar o `.innerText` por `.value`:

```
document.getElementById('fahrenheit').value = converte;
```

Em relação à decimais, coloque o atributo `step` no `input`. O `type="number"` por padrão só aceita números inteiros. O `step` permite redefinir esse padrão da forma que achar melhor:

```
<input type="number" step=".01"...
```

No exemplo acima, o valor `.01` irá permitir 2 casas decimais pulando de 1 em 1 centésimo.

Outros exemplos básicos:

```
step=".00"   -> 2 casas decimais pulando de 1 em 1 inteiro
step=".001"  -> 3 casas decimais pulando de 1 em 1 milésimo
step=".1"    -> 1 casa decimal pulando de 1 em 1 décimo
step=".10"   -> 2 casas decimais pulando de 1 em 1 décimo
step="any"   -> aceita qualquer valor float (sem número definido de casas decimais)
```

Answer (score 1):

Com é sua primeira vez, precisa colocar todas as informações, por exemplo, o `<form>`, mas, acabei criando um exemplo minimo:

```js
document.querySelector('#temp-form')
        .addEventListener('submit', calcular);


function calcular(e) 
{
  var celsius = document.getElementById('celsius');
  var principal = parseFloat(celsius.value);
  var converte = parseFloat((9 * principal + 160) / 5);
  document.getElementById('fahrenheit').innerText = converte
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<form id="temp-form" name="temp-form">
 <input type="text" id="celsius" name="celsius" />
 <button>Calcular</button>
</form>

<label id="fahrenheit"></label>
```

Comment: Pode ser que o código na pergunta não funcionou porque "fahrenheit" pode ser um campo `input`, dai `innerText` não vai funcionar

Comment: @RicardoPontual verdade, só fiz mesmo um exemplo mais ou menos como ele tinha escrito na pergunta...!